# java.io.File in j2mepolish not working

Tags: java, java-me, io, j2mepolish, nokia-s40

I need to  create an image in my application's sub-folder so that I am using java.io.File and java.io.FileOutputStream; but when I build the project , this error occurs :

```
error: cannot find symbol
    [javac]java.io.File

error: cannot find symbol
    [javac] import java.io.FileOutputStream;
```

How can I fix this or there is an another way to create the file?

Comment: Please upload your code as well.

Comment: those classes no existy in J2ME, file access is done using JSR-75.

Answer (score 1):

Import microedition, eg, 
import javax.microedition.io.file.FileConnection;